# facial animation

Tags: opengl, animation

I am developing a **3d facial animation application** in java using `opengl(jogl)` i had done the animation with **morph targets** and now i am trying to do a parametrized facial animation .

I can't attach the vertex of the face with the appropriate parameter,for example i have the parameter eyebrow length ,how could i know wish are the vertex of the eyebrows (face features),please please could anybody help me i'm using obj file to read the face model and face gen to create it.

I appreciate  your help .

Comment: Spelling, capitalization, spacing, etc.

Answer (score 2):

For each morph target you assign each vertex a weight, how strong it is influenced by the respective morph target. There's no algorithmic way to do this, this must be done manually.

Lightwave OBJ file format may not be ideal for storing the geometry in this case, since it lacks support for storing such auxiliary data. You may extend the file format, however this will probably clash with programs expecting a "normal" OBJ.

I strongly suggest using a format that has been designed to support any number of additional attributes. You may want to look at OpenCTM.

Comment: thank you for your help,you mean i use another format to store the face and associate it with the weight of each vertex,i understand that but my goal is to deform the neutral face to get the desired expression than generate the key frames to animate it and i still can't understand how to deform a specific area of the face for example the lips ,any idea? @datenwolf

Comment: Well, you need to associate that area to some kind of controller. I think it would be a good start for you to understand, how this association is done: It's a manual process performed by a 3D artist. The Blender wiki has some nice tutorials which may give you the general idea: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:Tutorials/Animation/BSoD/Character_Animation/Upper_body_armature http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:Tutorials/Animation/BSoD/Character_Animation/Upper_body_weight_painting http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:Tutorials/Animation/BSoD/Character_Animation/Lower_body_armature

Comment: Each controller effectively defines a translation-rotation transformation. For each vertex it is stored how strong a controller is influencing it (the weight). For each vertex the transformations are weighted summed, then the vertex transformed with the result, using a vertex shader.